# Android - ListView and Click Listeners

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onitemclick

I've a ListView `lv`. I set `OnItemClickListener` and `OnItemLongClickListener` on `lv`. But when `OnItemLongClick` is being called `OnItemClick` is being called too. So, I need to call `OnItemLongClick` without calling `OnItemClick`. How I can do that?

Excuse for my English, please.

**UPD** Here's some code

---

```
              lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
                            {       
                                    //blah-blah-blah
                            }
                    });
            lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView p1, View p2, int p3, long p4) {
                                            //blah-blah-blah
                                            return true;
                            }
            });
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: We are not SANTA who can guide you without looking into your code :)

Comment: Wow, I've added an Override and my code works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your missing `@Override` in `setOnItemLongClickListener`

Example:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1,int arg2, long arg3){
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);      
            final String Name = lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString();               

            // Make sth on click
        }});


        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    final int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Make sth on longclick
            return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code and it is working for on long press event also. On item click event is not firing when long pressed.

```
package com.example.spinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        String fuel[] = new String[] { "Select Any", "Petrol", "Diesel",
                "CNG Company Fitted", "CNG External Fitted" };
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fuel);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
         list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

         list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```